# JDBC 1064 SQL Syntax Error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-error-1064

I want to handle a MySQL database using JDBC from inside an operation of a Java Web Service.
I have :

```
stmt = conn.createStatement();

String query = "CREATE TABLE Basestations (Network_Id INT,"
                    + "Basestation_Id INT, Signal_Strength DOUBLE,"
                    + "Frequency DOUBLE, Network_Type VARCHAR(40), Max_Bitrate DOUBLE,"
                    + "Guaranteed_Bitrate DOUBLE, Net_Load INT," 
                    + "Provider VARCHAR(45), Range DOUBLE, X INT, Y INT,"
                    + "Port INT, Charging VARCHAR(40), Active BOOLEAN);";

stmt.execute(query);
```

to create my table, but this causes:

`INFO: SQL Exception:
INFO: State  : 42000
INFO: Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Range DOUBLE, X INT, Y INT,Port INT, Charging VARCHAR(40), Active BOOLEAN)' at line 1
INFO: Error  : 1064`

What is wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RANGE` is a [reserved keyword is MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html). Rather surround `Range` with a *`* (backtick).

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE Basestations (Network_Id INT,"
                    + "Basestation_Id INT, Signal_Strength DOUBLE,"
                    + "Frequency DOUBLE, Network_Type VARCHAR(40), Max_Bitrate DOUBLE,"
                    + "Guaranteed_Bitrate DOUBLE, Net_Load INT," 
                    + "Provider VARCHAR(45), `Range` DOUBLE, X INT, Y INT,"
                    + "Port INT, Charging VARCHAR(40), Active BOOLEAN);";
```

Answer (score 1):

RANGE is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html).
Use a backtick '`' to quote this field name.

Comment: I have read your answer just after the posting;) I can remove my answer, or we can ask nikos to accept your answer.

Comment: It's cool. It shows that our answers are legit. :-)

Comment: Yes, and they are almost equal, sometimes it happens. But you was first. Good luck!